# How to divide a length to the equal parts regarding to the reminder?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of boxes:

```
class Box {
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;
}
```

Suppose we need to create a table of boxes.

```
Box[][] table;
```

I know the size of the box and width, and height of the table. Here is my method for table building.

```
public Box[][] table(int boxSize, int xBound, int yBound) {
    Box[][] boxes = new Box[xBound / boxSize][xBound / boxSize];
    for (int x = 0; x < xBound; x += boxSize) {
        for (int y = 0; y < yBound; y += boxSize) {
            boxes[x % xBound / boxSize][y % yBound / boxSize] = new Box(x, y, x + boxSize, y + boxSize);
        }
    }
    return boxes;
}
```

But the problem is `reminder`. If we need to set the table width to 24 and height to 22 and to set box size to 5, in that case we get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. If reminder exists, I want to create a small box for it and add it to the table.

```
[0-5, 0-5]   | [5-10, 0-5] | [10-15, 0-5] | [15-20, 0-5] | [20-24, 0-5]
...
[0-5, 20-22] | ...
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the number of boxes like this:

```
Box[][] boxes = new Box[(xBound - 1) / boxSize + 1][(yBound - 1) / boxSize + 1];
```

Then, when you create each box, check that `x + boxSize` is not greater than `xBound`, and the same for `y`.